# Is there a C++ function which matches strings matched with the start of regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm currently creating a lexer and I want to match strings which is valid by the start of the regex.
(I'm not very good at English, I'll show you what that actually means)

The lexer consumes one char each time linearly.

For example I have the string `abca.sd` and the regex `[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+`.

At the start, the lexer consumes `a` but it doesn't match the regex using `std::regex_match`, which makes it unavailable and invalid.
What I really want is with consuming `a`, `abca.`, `abca.sd`, the lexer will decide it is all valid.

Comment: So you really want to check whether a given string could be the beginning portion of some longer string which does match a given regex? I suspect that's a very hard problem in general.

Comment: Since you're already consuming one char at a time, I would recommend looking into (stack based) finite state machines (FSMs), as they do exactly what you're asking. In fact, any good regex implementation uses such a FSM. (Actually, a regex expression defines a specific FSM). Notice, however, that this is not quite an easy topic. I guess there are already some freely aviable implementations to transform a regex expression into an usable FSM, but I don't know any.

Comment: @aschepler It's pretty easy if you have the source of and can modify the regex library in question.

Comment: I could see one of 2 ways to do this: a) if you don't look backwards or use very complicated expressions you can break the regex down into parts and do partial matches or b) you can fill the string with something that should match the remaining part of the regex before checking it.

Comment: However I think you're going about this the wrong way, a regex match is a very costly operation, maybe you could tell us more about what you're trying to achieve in the end to see if we can help you... Note: I saw you said a lexer but it really depends on how complicated the syntax you're trying to match is.

Comment: @xception Thanks for your opinion, I think the first way that suggests breaking down regex is the one which can solve it. Plus, I think it is the simplest way to solve the problem.

Comment: @xception I was trying to match strings with regex `".*?"`, however, when consuming one char each time, when consuming the first char `"`, that doesn't really match the regex, which makes a problem

Comment: @xception Well, maybe defining multiple classes which processes different matches  would be better than just one class which use regex to process because it might be less costly. (What the 'class' here is class which validates and checks the input char to see what category does the input string belong to...I can't explain that clearer because I am not really good at English.)

Comment: although very little is clear to me about what you're trying to achieve here but maybe there's a simpler solution than regex to your problem, I suggest you look at the desk calculator code examples from byarne stroustrup's book on C++ http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_code.html maybe you could adapt the examples to your needs (you seem to be quite good at english IMHO from what you said here)

Comment: there's a basic lexer example in there as well as a parser, the examples are relatively easy to understand (you can also read the text of the book if you're having trouble understanding them)

Comment: Why not just append `.*` or `[\s\S]*` at the end of these patterns to let the regex match until the end of the string with `regex_match`?